# Error while "Building wxWidgets" for FileZilla compilation: configure: error: X11 not found, please use --x-includes and/or --x-libraries options

Tags: wxwidgets, mingw-w64, filezilla, msys2

I am trying to compile **FileZilla3** in my Windows system by exactly following [this](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_under_Windows).

In the **MSys2** terminal, everything works fine till "Building SQLite"

In "Building wxWidgets", the steps mentioned are:

```
cd ~
git clone --branch WX_3_0_BRANCH --single-branch https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git wx3
cd wx3
./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-unicode --enable-printfposparam --without-libtiff --without-libjpeg --with-expat=builtin --with-libpng=builtin
make && make install
```

When I execute the third step, i.e.

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-unicode --enable-printfposparam --without-libtiff --without-libjpeg --with-expat=builtin --with-libpng=builtin
```

I get the error:

```
configure: error: X11 not found, please use --x-includes and/or --x-libraries options (see config.log for details)
```

The complete output of the *`configure`* command is:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-unicode --enable-printfposparam --without-libtiff --without-libjpeg --with-expat=builtin --with-libpng=builtin
configure: loading site script /etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-msys
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-msys
configure: WARNING: *** System type x86_64-pc-msys is unknown, assuming generic Unix and continuing nevertheless.
configure: WARNING: *** Please report the build results to wx-dev@lists.wxwidgets.org.
checking for --disable-gui... no
checking for --enable-monolithic... no
checking for --enable-plugins... no
checking for --without-subdirs... no
checking for --enable-official_build... no
checking for --disable-all-features... no
checking for --enable-universal... no
checking for --enable-nanox... no
checking for --enable-gpe... no
checking for toolkit... x11
checking for --with-libpng... builtin version
checking for --with-libjpeg... no
checking for --with-libtiff... no
checking for --without-libjbig... no
checking for --without-liblzma... no
checking for --with-libxpm... yes
checking for --with-libiconv... yes
checking for --with-libmspack... no
checking for --without-gtkprint... no
checking for --with-gnomevfs... no
checking for --with-libnotify... yes
checking for --with-hildon... no
checking for --with-opengl... auto
checking for --with-dmalloc... no
checking for --with-sdl... no
checking for --with-regex... yes
checking for --with-zlib... yes
checking for --with-expat... builtin version
checking for --with-macosx-sdk...
checking for --with-macosx-version-min...
checking for --enable-debug... default
checking for --disable-debug_flag... no
checking for --enable-debug_info... no
checking for --enable-debug_gdb... no
checking for --enable-debug_cntxt... no
checking for --enable-mem_tracing... no
checking for --disable-shared... no
checking for --enable-stl... no
checking for --enable-std_containers... no
checking for --enable-std_iostreams... yes
checking for --enable-std_string... yes
checking for --enable-std_string_conv_in_wxstring... no
checking for --disable-unicode... no
checking for --enable-mslu... no
checking for --enable-utf8... no
checking for --enable-utf8only... no
checking for --enable-extended_rtti... no
checking for --disable-optimise... no
checking for --enable-profile... no
checking for --enable-no_rtti... no
checking for --enable-no_exceptions... no
checking for --enable-permissive... no
checking for --enable-no_deps... no
checking for --disable-vararg_macros... no
checking for --enable-universal_binary... no
checking for --enable-macosx_arch... no
checking for --enable-compat26... no
checking for --disable-compat28... no
checking for --disable-rpath... no
checking for --enable-objc_uniquifying... no
checking for --disable-visibility... no
checking for --disable-tls... no
checking for --enable-intl... yes
checking for --enable-xlocale... yes
checking for --enable-config... yes
checking for --enable-protocols... yes
checking for --enable-ftp... yes
checking for --enable-http... yes
checking for --enable-fileproto... yes
checking for --enable-sockets... yes
checking for --enable-ipv6... no
checking for --enable-ole... yes
checking for --enable-dataobj... yes
checking for --enable-ipc... yes
checking for --enable-baseevtloop... yes
checking for --enable-epollloop... yes
checking for --enable-selectloop... yes
checking for --enable-any... yes
checking for --enable-apple_ieee... yes
checking for --enable-arcstream... yes
checking for --enable-base64... yes
checking for --enable-backtrace... yes
checking for --enable-catch_segvs... yes
checking for --enable-cmdline... yes
checking for --enable-datetime... yes
checking for --enable-debugreport... yes
checking for --enable-dialupman... yes
checking for --enable-dynlib... yes
checking for --enable-dynamicloader... yes
checking for --enable-exceptions... yes
checking for --enable-ffile... yes
checking for --enable-file... yes
checking for --enable-filehistory... yes
checking for --enable-filesystem... yes
checking for --enable-fontenum... yes
checking for --enable-fontmap... yes
checking for --enable-fs_archive... yes
checking for --enable-fs_inet... yes
checking for --enable-fs_zip... yes
checking for --enable-fsvolume... yes
checking for --enable-fswatcher... yes
checking for --enable-geometry... yes
checking for --enable-log... yes
checking for --enable-longlong... yes
checking for --enable-mimetype... yes
checking for --enable-printfposparam... yes
checking for --enable-snglinst... yes
checking for --enable-sound... yes
checking for --enable-stdpaths... yes
checking for --enable-stopwatch... yes
checking for --enable-streams... yes
checking for --enable-sysoptions... yes
checking for --enable-tarstream... yes
checking for --enable-textbuf... yes
checking for --enable-textfile... yes
checking for --enable-timer... yes
checking for --enable-variant... yes
checking for --enable-zipstream... yes
checking for --enable-url... yes
checking for --enable-protocol... yes
checking for --enable-protocol_http... yes
checking for --enable-protocol_ftp... yes
checking for --enable-protocol_file... yes
checking for --enable-threads... yes
checking for --enable-iniconf... no
checking for --enable-regkey... yes
checking for --enable-docview... yes
checking for --enable-help... yes
checking for --enable-mshtmlhelp... yes
checking for --enable-html... yes
checking for --enable-htmlhelp... yes
checking for --enable-xrc... yes
checking for --enable-aui... yes
checking for --enable-propgrid... yes
checking for --enable-ribbon... yes
checking for --enable-stc... yes
checking for --enable-constraints... yes
checking for --enable-loggui... yes
checking for --enable-logwin... yes
checking for --enable-logdialog... yes
checking for --enable-mdi... yes
checking for --enable-mdidoc... yes
checking for --enable-mediactrl... auto
checking for --enable-gstreamer8... no
checking for --enable-richtext... yes
checking for --enable-postscript... yes
checking for --enable-printarch... yes
checking for --enable-svg... yes
checking for --enable-webkit... yes
checking for --enable-webview... yes
checking for --enable-graphics_ctx... yes
checking for --enable-clipboard... yes
checking for --enable-dnd... yes
checking for --disable-controls... no
checking for --enable-markup... yes
checking for --enable-accel... yes
checking for --enable-animatectrl... yes
checking for --enable-bannerwindow... yes
checking for --enable-artstd... yes
checking for --enable-arttango... auto
checking for --enable-bmpbutton... yes
checking for --enable-bmpcombobox... yes
checking for --enable-button... yes
checking for --enable-calendar... yes
checking for --enable-caret... yes
checking for --enable-checkbox... yes
checking for --enable-checklst... yes
checking for --enable-choice... yes
checking for --enable-choicebook... yes
checking for --enable-collpane... yes
checking for --enable-colourpicker... yes
checking for --enable-combobox... yes
checking for --enable-comboctrl... yes
checking for --enable-commandlinkbutton... yes
checking for --enable-dataviewctrl... yes
checking for --enable-datepick... yes
checking for --enable-detect_sm... yes
checking for --enable-dirpicker... yes
checking for --enable-display... yes
checking for --enable-editablebox... yes
checking for --enable-filectrl... yes
checking for --enable-filepicker... yes
checking for --enable-fontpicker... yes
checking for --enable-gauge... yes
checking for --enable-grid... yes
checking for --enable-headerctrl... yes
checking for --enable-hyperlink... yes
checking for --enable-imaglist... yes
checking for --enable-infobar... yes
checking for --enable-listbook... yes
checking for --enable-listbox... yes
checking for --enable-listctrl... yes
checking for --enable-notebook... yes
checking for --enable-notifmsg... yes
checking for --enable-odcombobox... yes
checking for --enable-popupwin... yes
checking for --enable-prefseditor... yes
checking for --enable-radiobox... yes
checking for --enable-radiobtn... yes
checking for --enable-richmsgdlg... yes
checking for --enable-richtooltip... yes
checking for --enable-rearrangectrl... yes
checking for --enable-sash... yes
checking for --enable-scrollbar... yes
checking for --enable-searchctrl... yes
checking for --enable-slider... yes
checking for --enable-spinbtn... yes
checking for --enable-spinctrl... yes
checking for --enable-splitter... yes
checking for --enable-statbmp... yes
checking for --enable-statbox... yes
checking for --enable-statline... yes
checking for --enable-stattext... yes
checking for --enable-statusbar... yes
checking for --enable-taskbaricon... yes
checking for --enable-tbarnative... yes
checking for --enable-textctrl... yes
checking for --enable-timepick... yes
checking for --enable-tipwindow... yes
checking for --enable-togglebtn... yes
checking for --enable-toolbar... yes
checking for --enable-toolbook... yes
checking for --enable-treebook... yes
checking for --enable-treectrl... yes
checking for --enable-treelist... yes
checking for --enable-commondlg... yes
checking for --enable-aboutdlg... yes
checking for --enable-choicedlg... yes
checking for --enable-coldlg... yes
checking for --enable-filedlg... yes
checking for --enable-finddlg... yes
checking for --enable-fontdlg... yes
checking for --enable-dirdlg... yes
checking for --enable-msgdlg... yes
checking for --enable-numberdlg... yes
checking for --enable-splash... yes
checking for --enable-textdlg... yes
checking for --enable-tipdlg... yes
checking for --enable-progressdlg... yes
checking for --enable-wizarddlg... yes
checking for --enable-menus... yes
checking for --enable-miniframe... yes
checking for --enable-tooltips... yes
checking for --enable-splines... yes
checking for --enable-mousewheel... yes
checking for --enable-validators... yes
checking for --enable-busyinfo... yes
checking for --enable-hotkey... auto
checking for --enable-joystick... yes
checking for --enable-metafile... auto
checking for --enable-dragimage... yes
checking for --enable-accessibility... no
checking for --enable-uiactionsim... yes
checking for --enable-dctransform... yes
checking for --enable-webviewwebkit... yes
checking for --enable-palette... yes
checking for --enable-image... yes
checking for --enable-gif... yes
checking for --enable-pcx... yes
checking for --enable-tga... yes
checking for --enable-iff... yes
checking for --enable-pnm... yes
checking for --enable-xpm... yes
checking for --enable-ico_cur... yes
checking for --enable-dccache... yes
checking for --enable-ps-in-msw... yes
checking for --enable-ownerdrawn... yes
checking for --enable-uxtheme... yes
checking for --enable-wxdib... yes
checking for --enable-webviewie... yes
checking for --enable-autoidman... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the Intel C compiler... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether we are using the Intel C++ compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for langinfo.h... no
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... no
checking for cxxabi.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking size of short... 2
checking size of void *... 8
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 4
checking size of size_t... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of wchar_t... 2
checking for va_copy... yes
checking whether the compiler supports variadic macros... yes
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking if large file support is available... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for iostream... yes
checking if C++ compiler supports the explicit keyword... yes
checking for std::wstring in <string>... yes
checking for std::istream... yes
checking for std::ostream... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking type_traits usability... yes
checking type_traits presence... yes
checking for type_traits... yes
checking for __sync_fetch_and_add and __sync_sub_and_fetch builtins... yes
checking for libraries directories... /usr/lib
checking for cos... yes
checking for floor... yes
checking if floating point functions link without -lm... yes
checking for strtoull... yes
checking for pkg-config... /mingw64/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
configure: WARNING: Defaulting to the builtin regex library for Unicode build.
checking for zlib.h >= 1.1.4... yes
checking for zlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for deflate in -lz... yes
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found, please use --x-includes and/or --x-libraries options (see config.log for details)
```

I get the same error on trying out any of these 2 also:

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-unicode --enable-printfposparam --without-libtiff --without-libjpeg --with-expat=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --x-includes=/mingw64/include/X11
```

```
./configure --prefix="$HOME/prefix" --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-unicode --enable-printfposparam --without-libtiff --without-libjpeg --with-expat=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --x-includes=/mingw64/include
```

Kindly help

Comment: do you want it to run from Windows or from MSYS environment? In any case - try to use "--with-msw" option pass to configure.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for help! I want to run the configure from MSYS2 environment. When I tried it using "--with-msw" option, I got the error *configure: error: unknown system type x86_64-pc-msys.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be running configure from "msys" [subsystem](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/MSYS2-introduction#subsystems) of MSYS2 which is a POSIX-like system not meant to be used for compilation.

You should launch `mingw64.exe` or `mingw32.exe` instead to build native MSW software using MinGW and then configure should work just fine there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be working fine:) Just have one major doubt. [This](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_under_Windows) mentions *FileZilla's shell extension needs to be build both for 32bit as well as 64bit, hence we're going to need compilers for both 32bit and 64bit.* (mentioned in "Installing the compiler toolchain"). So, do I need to build in both mingw64.exe & mingw32.exe ?

Comment: Would there any problem if I build in both mingw64.exe & mingw32.exe?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to build both 32- and 64-bit versions in parallel.